# Change Label Color

Tags: python, kivy

Help please i'm trying to use objectproperty to change the color of the label. The function works because it prints out in the console. The label color or text doesnt change though and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
<Box3@BoxLayout>:
    GridLayout:

        indicator: my_indicator
        cols: 1
        size: root.width/3, root.height/2

        Label:
            id: my_indicator
            pos: self.pos
            text: 'test'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

```
class main_kv(GridLayout):

    indicator = ObjectProperty(Widget)
    activate = ObjectProperty(None)

    def changeColour(self):

        self.indicator.color = 1,0,1,1
        self.indicator.text = 'changed'
        print('button clicked')

    pass
```

```
        Button:
            id: activate
            text: 'Arm'
            on_press: app.root.changeColour()
            background_color: (0.4, 0.7, 0.8, 1.0)
            pos: self.parent.center
            font_size: 40
            opacity: 0.8
```

Comment: It doesn't run when i do that just crashes.                                                                                              Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEG. Does it make a different if the label is on a different kv file to the main kv file that runs all the other files.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the init function to create the indicator and activate objects:

```
class main_kv(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        self.indicator = ObjectProperty(Widget)
        self.activate = ObjectProperty(None)

    def changeColour(self):

        self.indicator.color = 1,0,1,1
        self.indicator.text = 'changed'
        print('button clicked')

    pass
```

Comment: When i do it the normal way and i change the object type from widget to none, i get this error.    File "/home/lay/PycharmProjects/AlarmTwo/AlarmApp.py", line 30, in changeColour
     self.indicator.color = 1,0,0,1
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'color'   but im pretty sure that i created the two id's i need to make in the kv files.